# How to get documents that are differents by value field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using ElasticSearch 6.3. 
Scenario: dozens of thousand documents has "123" field with "blabla" value in most of those. A few has "blabla blo" in that field. These occupy last places in query results if I set up size: 10000 (if default size, they doesn't appear). But I really want both unique records: one with these field "123": "blabla" and that one with field "123":"blabla blo".
I`m using wildcard and getting all 10000 documents. Only need those two.
I'm going to feed a select tag HTML with thats records, but only two of them ideally!
**Query body:**

```
{   
    "query": {
        "wildcard":{
            "324" : {
                "value":"*b*"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10000,
    "_source": ["324"]  
}
```

How I should make it? The concept would be similar to find records which value aren't fully duplicated in that field, I supose.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what aggs are for!

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "324": {
        "value": "*b*"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "324_uniques": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "324",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`field` could be `324` OR `324.keyword`, depending on your mapping.

Comment: Just note that wildcard queries with prefix wildcards can kill the performance of your cluster.